# Is it possible to use EV3 MicroPython with Windows 7?

Tags: ev3, software, python

I have been trying to get python on my EV3 brick using an EV3 MicroPython SD card image as described on the Lego website. The EV3 brick seem fine with its new OS.

Instead my problems are at the computer end. When connecting the EV3 to my PC by USB cable and the Visual Studio Code editor (as prescribed by the Lego documentation) I can find and connect to the EV3 brick. But as soon as I try to actually do something with the connected device I get a blue screen of death.

According to the Lego homepage the systems requirements for EV3 MicroPython is Windows 10. I use Windows 7 on my computer which by itself should explain the problems. Nevertheless my question is if this seems plausible? Have others had the same problem? Is there any other way to use Python programming on my EV3 brick without having to change OS on my computers?

Comment: Does the BSOD offer any clues to what causes the crash?

Comment: There should be a dump file created here %SystemRoot%memory.dmp i.e C:\Windows\memory.dmp If you could make that file somehow available, I or others could analyze it.

Comment: I haven't heard of this causing a BSOD before (I wrote a significant portion of the software in question, so I would be more likely to hear user feedback than most people :-) ). It sounds like a hardware problem with your computer. Is there another computer you could use instead?

Comment: What's the stop code (usually on second paragraph)? What's the bugcheck code (i.e. 0x00000f or something)?

Comment: Apparently Windows 10/8/7 all had problems with freezing when USB devices were inserted, and only one other guy out there had a BSOD instead. This might help: https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/my-computer-freezes-when-usb-plugged-in-windows-10-7.html

Comment: See if the USB port is not physically damaged or try putting another USB device into your computer.

Answer (score 2):

The official answer is **NO**.

EV3 Python only supports Windows 10 or version 1803 or newer.
The page from the Documentation listing the system requirements are linked below:

[EV3 Documentation - Minimum system requirements](https://education.lego.com/en-us/product-resources/mindstorms-ev3/downloads/system-requirements)

That being said, there might be some trick to still getting it to work, but this is outside the supported scope.

Everything hinges on the **EV3 MicroPython extension**, and without it, you might be able to detect, but not use the EV3 block.

The blue screen of death seems like a bit of an overreaction, so some troubleshooting would not go amiss there, but using 3rd party extensions in an unsupported capacity can lead to hazardous results.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no! The EV3 software does not support Windows 7 or Windows 8. Because of how long ago Windows 7 was made, and the time EV3 was made, it simply cannot support it.

Or maybe *it is* your fault. The USB cord might be damaged or something, we don't know.

Comment: Hi @Nerd! Do you have any source to prove this? Do you even know that the EV3 already comes with a USB to connect to the computer?

Comment: @mindstormsboi Of corse i do! I watched a unboxing video on youtube a couple of months ago and it came with a USB, i just said that the guy should probably get a new USB cable cause the other one may be fried or a wire ripped a little

Comment: @mindstormsboi when i was 6 in my stem class at school i remember i had a windows 7 computer and we used EV3 and i connected it to my computer i dont exactly know what happened but something popped up on the screen telling me it could not support windows 7 or something

Comment: Did all of the other students have the same problem? Were you using Chromebooks?

Comment: Yes but not all students were using chromebooks some were using a pc and it still did not work for them